# Correct Method to Delete Delta Lake Partion on AWS s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I need to delete a Delta Lake partition with associated AWS s3 files and then need to make sure AWS Athena displays this change. The purpose is because I need to rerun some code to re-populate the data.

I tried this

```py
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)
deltaTable.delete("extract_date = '2022-03-01'") #extract date is the partition
```

And it completed with no errors but the files on s3 still exist and Athena still shows the data even after running `MSK REPAIR TABLE` after the delete. Can someone advise the best way to delete partitions and update Athena?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you performed delete operation, data is still there because Delta tables have history, and actual deletion of the data will happen only when you execute [VACUUM operation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table) and operation time will be older than default retention period (7 days).  If you want to remove data faster, then you can run VACUUM command with parameter `RETAIN XXX HOURS`, but this may require setting some additional properties to enforce that - refer documentation for more details.

Comment: After running the vacuum operation will I need to do anything in AWS Athena?

Comment: as soon as VACUUM finishes, Athena should see only modified data

Comment: I added the vacuum process but the files are still on s3 and being referenced by Athena. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you changed retention time?

Comment: I did and set it for 24hrs as I thought this would catch the change in those versions. This appears to work as I reduce the time. Currently at 3 hrs. I take this is due to version time due to the delete and not when it was created?

Comment: Yes, that’s a time when these versions were deleted…

Comment: Just as an added note. I had to run this command on Athena as it was throwing an error about a missing parquet. ALTER TABLE <table name> drop if exists PARTITION(extract_date = "2022-03-01").

Answer (score 0):

will add to Alex's answer, if you want to shorten retention period less than 7 days, you have to change configuration property: `spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled to false.`

from original docs:

> Delta Lake has a safety check to prevent you from running a dangerous
> VACUUM command. If you are certain that there are no operations being
> performed on this table that take longer than the retention interval
> you plan to specify, you can turn off this safety check by setting the
> Spark configuration property
> spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled to false.

Answer (score 0):

from my observation, I can say that VACUUM doesnt delete s3 files. I've used Vacuum with default retain hours(7 days) and i still see the parq files on s3 even after 7 days have elapsed since the cmd was run